# Cloudberry Glacier items re-appear after deletion

Tags: amazon-glacier, explorer, cloudberry

I am trying to delete several Glacier vaults using CloudBerry Explorer (Pro) 5.2.0.26.  I first request the inventory, wait until the archives are visible in CloudBerry, select all the high level folders in the vault, and click Delete.  I watch as the parallel tasks run through the folders and delete everything.

After waiting for a day (and in some cases longer) I try to delete the Vault and receive the error that it is not empty (from both CloudBerry and the AWS Glacier console).  When I go back into the CloudBerry UI, there is no content in the vault, but when I do another "Get Inventory" and wait another several hours until the tasks complete, the content has re-appeared!

Well, not quite: it seems that only folders that are empty are failing to get deleted, as well as the parent folders that contain them.

I have repeated this entire process multiple times, and cannot get CloudBerry to remove the empty folders nor delete the Vault. Is this a CloudBerry bug?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Since you have CloudBerry Pro you should have support from CloudBerry. I suggest you raise a support ticket. Could be a bug.

Comment: Good idea, I'll post back here with any resolution